# Grid with Bootstrap carousel not displaying correctly.

Tags: grid, bootstrap

I am using bootstrap carousel with EE's Grid and the page is not displaying correctly. All 3 slides are displaying on top of each other. I think its the "active" class is being applied to each slide in each div. I think I need a conditional on the active class but I don't know how to do it.

here is the code:

```
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-example">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>


            <div class="carousel-inner">
                  {exp:channel:entries channel="slider" {snp-disable}}  
                  {home_page_slider}
                <div class="item active"><img src="{home_page_slider:slider_image}" alt="Slide"></div>
                   {/home_page_slider}
                    {/exp:channel:entries}

             </div>


            <a href="#carousel-example" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#carousel-example" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="slider" {snp-disable}}
{if count == "1"}
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-example">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
{/if}

    {home_page_slider}
    <div class="item{if home_page_slider:count == "1"} active{/if}">
        <img src="{home_page_slider:slider_image}" alt="Slide">
    </div>
    {/home_page_slider}

{if count == total_results}
</div>
<a href="#carousel-example" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carousel-example" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That way if the entries loop fails to get your content, none of the carousel markup would display either

Comment: Works smooth. no bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the count and output the active class in the first item that you iterate:

```
{if home_page_slider:count == "1"}active{/if}
```

Or specifically using your example:

```
<div class="item{if home_page_slider:count == "1"} active{/if}">
```

Comment: This one causes the each slide to bounce (reposition) as it become active.